# Capturing a particular character from a string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, file-io

I have a file with contents like this:

```
HFH_F_OPL_J0                                       ;comment1
HIJ_I_AAA_V2_DSD                                   ;comment2
ALE_H_FB_V1                                        ;comment3
ZXZPOIF_P                                              ;comment4
RST0DREK_S                                              ;comment5
```

I need to match the single character, always present after the first underscore, and always one of [H, I, F, P, L, S] *only*.

What regex is to be used for this?

```
/(\w{3,})_([S|I|P|F|L|H]{1})(.*)\;/
```

does not give the right results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anchors and change the first `\w` to `[A-Z]` because `\w` should also match `_`. Now, get the Character you want from group index 1.

```
/^[A-Z]{3,}_([SIPFLH]).*;/
```

or

```
/^[^_]{3,}_\K[SIPFLH](?=.*;)/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fM5jO5/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you trust your data then there's no reason to check the value of the character right after the first underscore -- you can just grab it and use it

This short Perl program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    say $1 if /_(.)/;
}

__DATA__
HFH_F_OPL_J0                                       ;comment1
HIJ_I_AAA_V2_DSD                                   ;comment2
ALE_H_FB_V1                                        ;comment3
ZXZPOIF_P                                              ;comment4
RST0DREK_S
```

### output

```
F
I
H
P
S
```

If you want to be slightly more secure then you can use a character class instead of a dot, which changes that line of my code to

```
say $1 if /_([HIFPLS])/;
```

The output is identical to that of the original code